# Does xcorr corretly calulate the lag between two sets of data?

Tags: matlab

Now I am working on sound localization algorithm. I use TDOA method. I use xcorr function in matlab. Suppose the two signals are sine waves. I found if phase difference of the two waves is pi, I can get two peaks in cross correlation result, which values are equal. So I don't konw whose phase is lead and which one is lag. If phase difference is more than pi,for example one wave is lead another several periods, the result is wrong. I used voice signal to test the algorithm, I found if the phase difference was more than pi, the results sometimes were wrong.
I have read several papers, most of which use cross correlation algorithm to identify sound location. But I don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: Have you taken into consideration of your sampling frequency?

Comment: The lag or lead of sine signals (of the same frequency) is ambigous, because the sine function is periodic. There should be an infinite number of equal peaks in the cross correlation signal. Additionally cross correlation is defined in the time domain. Therefore the phase difference is meaningless here. Differences have to be expressed in terms of seconds or number of samples.